# How to include MSM into a MSP with WiX

Tags: merge, module, wix, merge-module, msi-patch

I am using WiX for building MSI and MSP.

In my MSI, I have an MSM file present.

I made some changes to the files in the MSM and re generated the same.

Now I wanted to create a patch/MSP with the change in MSM included.

Please help me to create a MSP with the updated MSM file.

Answer (score 0):

*An MSP - **a Windows Installer Patch** - is merely a distribution / packaging mechanism for an MSI update that is already working as a full package*.

Hence the process of making an MSP that contains the updated files - merge module or not - is to make two full MSI packages for the different versions and then to make an MSP package out of the differences between them.

This thorough tutorial explains WiX patch creation in full detail: [Using Patch Creation Properties](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/patching/patch_building.html). Patching is complicated and error prone, and you should be aware of the [restrictions for patches](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/patching/patch_restrictions.html).